# laravel 5.2 how to use the count query with where query

Tags: sql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have tried every where all examples I came across but still have the same problem error '**htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**'
I need to select count from the database and would like to use the raw select as i will have more flexibility on it but any point towards the right direction will be appreciated here is what i have been doing'

```
$totalOpen = DB::table('dam')
    ->select(array('dam.*', DB::raw('COUNT(dam.mivisjobid) as followers')))
    ->join('miviswf','miviswf.mivisid','=','dam.mivisjobid')
    ->whereRaw( 'miviswf.mivisid=dam.mivisjobid')
    ->whereIn('miviswf.Status', $inputIds) // pass an array
    ->orderBy('miviswf.datetimesubmitted', 'ASC');'
```

and i get this error **'htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View:** '

Comment: Can you share the value of `$inputIds` and where is `htmlentities()` in your code ?

Comment: $inputIds = ['OPEN','AMEND'];

Comment: Can you share the complete Exception error with line number and map the line number to your code? Also, you have a [count method](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_count) you may consider using before instead of raw queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine

```
 DB::table(' dam')
      ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, don't use array inside the select method

```
->select('dam.*', DB::raw('COUNT(dam.mivisjobid) as followers'))
```

for reference:
     https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects

Comment: ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\xxxxx\xxxx\xxxx\resources\views\admin.blade.php)